# Makefile - Make dependency only if file doesn't exist

Tags: makefile, dependencies, target, file-exists

Like the title says, I would like to make a dependency only if a certain file does not exist, NOT every time it updates.

I have a root directory (the one with the makefile) and in it a sub-directory called "example". In my root directory are four .h files (functions.h, parser.h, node.h, and exception.h) which I would like to copy to the "example" sub-directory if those .h files do not already exist in "examples".

Unfortunately I can not just make a standard dependency to check for the header files in "example" because each time I copy the header files from root to "example", the header files in "example" will be considered updated and will trigger that dependency each time I run make. I would like for a way to have my makefile copy the header files from the root directory to "example" only if they do not exist in "example".

Comment: The manual is very, very clear that automatic variables (such as `$@`) are valid _only_ within the recipe.  You cannot use them in targets, in prerequisites, or in make conditional statements (because those are expanded while the makefile is read in).  In those cases, `$@` expands to the empty string.

Comment: I see, but because I append "example/" there's something for the ifeq() to still evaluate to false. Thanks for clearing that up. I've edited my post to focus on the remaining issue.

Comment: Another solution to your problem can be `cp -p --update`: _copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing_.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is what [order-only prerequisites/dependencies](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) are for:

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (`|`) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only.

In your case:

```
examples/%.h : | %.h
    cp $| $@
```

See also: [Order-only prerequisites do not show up in `$^` or `$+`.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#index-g_t_0024_003c-967)

Comment: If you are using GNU make (and you probably are), this is a great answer.

Comment: @reinierpost I am not sure why would one use any other make.

Comment: In the past, I've been stuck with other `make`s but indeed, that was a long time ago.

Comment: Thanks, this example worked but I'm not sure I understand it. I thought order-only means that if the dependency "%.h" doesn't exist or is updated it would NOT trigger the target "examples/%.h". Furthermore, "examples/%.h" is a dependency of its own that should be triggered any time files from "root" are copied to "examples" since it updates the files "examples/%.h". This however is not the behavior meaning it does what I want it to, but not what I expect. Could you elaborate on what's happening in your solution?

Comment: @Daniel `make` does not check the timestamp of order-only dependencies. Which means that it creates `examples/%.h` but does not update it when its prerequisite `%.h` changes.

Comment: So if %.h is executed not necessarily the rule examples/%.h will be executed. Just when examples/%.h is executed, %.h is checked and if newer than, is executed.

Comment: @DavidKennedy `%.h` timestamp is never checked, your summary doesn't sound right.

Comment: Sorry, @MaximEgorushkin. The main difference using order-only is that it ignores updates but keeps looking at the file existence, right?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the suggested answer to work for some reason, and so my search led me to other answers that us `@test -f myfile` or variations thereof.

But if you (like me) don't like the usability of printing a big `make: *** [...] Error 1` simply because a condition is fulfilled, then there exists an alternative solution:

```
conditional_buid:
ifeq (,$(wildcard path/to/file))
    gcc ...
endif
```

If the file exists, nothing will happen. If the file does not exist, it will simply build. This probably also enables us to chain commands because `make` will not exit prematurely.

The command may be extended/modified by `ifneq`, `else`, etc.